# python selenium: create a loop for this script

Tags: python, selenium

I have this code below that currently works but just needs a cleaner more concise form of it...How do i handle the variables in a loop?

```
from random import *
import random
import time
from selenium import webdriver

a = 3
b = 3
c = 2
d = 3
f = 1
g = 3
h = 3
j = 1

a1 = 2
b1 = 3
c1 = 2
d1 = 3
f1 = 3
g1 = 1
h1 = 3
j1 = 3

(8 MORE GROUPS OF VARIABLES below this in the script)


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver\geckodriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("someurl")
driver.maximize_window()

usernameStr = 'username'
passwordStr = 'password'
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
username.send_keys(usernameStr)
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
password.send_keys(passwordStr)

enter = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Log In']")
enter.click()
time.sleep(2)

time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/label[' + str(b) + ']/span[1]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(div[3]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/label[' + str(c) + ']/span[1]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(div[4]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/label[' + str(d) + ']/span[3]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(div[5]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/label[' + str(f) + ']/span[3]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(div[6]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/label[' + str(g) + ']/span[1]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(div[7]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/label[' + str(h) + ']/span[3]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(div[8]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/label[' + str(j) + ']/span[3]').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="TabsContainer"]/div/label[2]/div').click()
#SUBMIT
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='by-octane']//span[1]").click()


#GROUP #2
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/label[' + str(b1) + ']/span[1]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(div[3]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/label[' + str(c1) + ']/span[1]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(div[4]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/label[' + str(d1) + ']/span[3]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(div[5]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/label[' + str(f1) + ']/span[3]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(div[6]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/label[' + str(g1) + ']/span[1]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(div[7]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/label[' + str(h1) + ']/span[3]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(div[8]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/label[' + str(j1) + ']/span[3]').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="TabsContainer"]/div/label[2]/div').click()
#SUBMIT
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='by-octane']//span[1]").click()
```

(8 MORE GROUPS BELOW)

I need a more concise way to handle these variables so i can put everything in a python loop but i am at a loss what to do. Help needed here.

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and post relevant html as well. How this will work `driver.find_element_by_xpathdiv[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/label[' + str(b1) + ']/span[1]').click()` ??

Comment: Post relevant HTML so that other contributor can help you on that.

Comment: Store all your variables in an array and then index them with i.

Comment: You can do something like arr= [[2,3 1]]  for the first row in group 1 and replace the areas that change as well. With arr[i][0] for div[2] , arr[i][1] replaces str(b) and so on.